# WHAT is the emacs tutorial command?

Tags: help

It says `C-h t` in a vague forum manual  but I don't have that, how do I access this feature.

Comment: `C-h t` means to depress the `control` key and hold it down, and while holding it down press the letter `h` one time; then, release both of those keys and press the letter `t` one time.

Comment: C-h is bind to different backspace control so I want a command to execute after `M-x tutorial` or something fundamental.

Comment: The command is `help-with-tutorial`. P.S. I think you'd be much happier in the long run if you don't do things like "bind `C-h` to different backspace control". Why exactly do you want to do that?

Comment: I also wanted to use `C-i C-j` for up and down navigation but `C-i` is something important it seems, so I use `C-l C-j`

Comment: To ascertain the default keybinding for a particular function, start Emacs without any user configuration; aka `emacs -Q` and then type `C-h k` and then the keyboard shortcut at issue -- this will open up a `*Help*` buffer that describes the function to which the keyboard shortcut is bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `M-x help-with-tutorial` (`M` is the `Alt` key).

But I suggest using `M-x help-with-tutorial-spec-language`,

[image]